# Rails 3 caching: Calling Sweeper independent from HTTP request (eg from background process)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I set up page caching using Nginx + Passenger + Rails 3 and it works quite well. But there is a big flaw: I change the content of the website via different processes (via normal HTTP requests and the corresponding controllers, via background processes which do not involve any HTTP requests and via RailsAdmin with different controllers).

Is there a way to expire the page cache directly from the model. The best would be to use a classic observer wich expires the cache when an object is changed etc.

The best recipe I found so far was this:

http://broadcastingadam.com/2011/05/advanced_caching_in_rails

But it didn't work for me.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thanks!